# Quantum Chemistry Kronecker Delta formality

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In semi-empirical quantum chemistry, one frequently encounters the so called [*zero differential overlap*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_differential_overlap) approximation

$$\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle = \delta_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\lambda\sigma} \langle \mu \mu | \lambda \lambda \rangle .$$

Why is it rather not written as

$$\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle = \delta_{\mu\nu}\delta_{\lambda\sigma} \langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle = \langle \mu \mu | \lambda \lambda \rangle $$

since on the right hand side of the first equation there are no $\nu$ nor $\sigma$ contained anymore.
So either all four variables **plus** the Kronecker Deltas (middle expression of second equation), or only the "remaining" variables after evaluation of the Kronecker deltas (last expression of second equation).

Comment: I think there is a summation which can't be seen in this notation. You have tensors of rank 2 there.

Comment: Can you expand on your comment a bit? I dont understand where do you suspect a summation.

Comment: Something like this $\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle =\langle \chi^{\lambda},\chi_{\mu}\rangle \langle \chi^{\sigma},\chi_{\nu}\rangle=\langle \chi^{\lambda},\chi_{\mu} \rangle \langle \delta_{\lambda}^{\sigma}\chi^{\lambda},\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}\chi_{\mu} \rangle=\delta_{\lambda}^{\sigma}\delta_{\nu}^{\mu}\langle \chi^{\lambda},\chi_{\mu} \rangle \langle \chi^{\lambda}, \chi_{\mu}\rangle$

Comment: So you have the deltas acting only on the second inner product (or the first, but only on one of them). Actually it would be better to change the indexes to $\lambda '$ and $\mu '$ in the second inner product in order to not confuse them. But there is no problem...

Answer (score 3):

$\mu$ and $\nu$ are dummy variables, they can take any values from $1$ to $N$. As such, you cannot evaluate the Kronecker delta, before specifying $\mu$ and $\nu$ are. For example, $\delta_{14} = 0$, and $\delta_{NN} = 1$, but that is only because you have been given what $\mu$ and $\nu$ are.

So the first line still contains $\nu$ and $\sigma$! What the equation is saying is that, when $\mu = \nu$, **and** $\lambda = \sigma$, for any $\mu, \lambda = 1, \cdots, N$, then $\langle \mu \mu | \lambda \lambda \rangle = \langle \mu \mu | \lambda \lambda \rangle $, which is obviously true (though it doesn't tell you what the numerical value is). **But if any one of those conditions is not true** then $\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle = 0$.

Now what you wrote doesn't make sense. If $\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle = \delta_{\mu \nu} \delta_{\lambda \sigma} \langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle $ then $1 = \delta_{\mu \nu} \delta_{\lambda \sigma}$ (if $\langle \mu \nu | \lambda \sigma \rangle \neq 0$). But this is obviously a false statement, since if say $\mu = 1, \nu = 2$ then we have $ 1 = 0$.

The bottom line is that $\mu, \nu, \lambda, \sigma$ are dummy variables, and you cannot evaluate the Kronecker delta without being given what the two indices are.

Comment: I get the mechanism of the Kronecker delta and now I also get how to read the first equation. So in the integral of the right hand side in the first equation, the second $\mu$ is implicitly the $\nu$, which I plug in for the $\nu$ in the first Kronecker delta.